# What does it mean when yacc {code} are in the middle?

Tags: yacc, bison

```
extdefs:
    {$<ttype>$ = NULL_TREE; } extdef
    | extdefs {$<ttype>$ = NULL_TREE; } extdef
    ;
```

Why is it in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be everywhere. Sometimes it's useful to have something done in between the tokens, especially in this kind of **or** expressions.

In the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html) description of the `yacc` utility it's said that:

> Actions can occur anywhere in a rule
>   (not just at the end); an action can
>   access values returned by actions to
>   its left, and in turn the value it
>   returns can be accessed by actions to
>   its right. An action appearing in the
>   middle of a rule shall be equivalent
>   to replacing the action with a new
>   non-terminal symbol and adding an
>   empty rule with that non-terminal
>   symbol on the left-hand side. The
>   semantic action associated with the
>   new rule shall be equivalent to the
>   original action. The use of actions
>   within rules might introduce conflicts
>   that would not otherwise exist.

Comment: What does `$<ttype>$` mean here?

Comment: @assem: This is bison-only. Refer to the 4.8 in bison documentation. I mean, i don't use bison-specific features:)